# How to reuse a Hiera array in Puppet?

Tags: arrays, puppet, hiera

**Aim**

The aim is to reuse hiera arrays to avoid code duplication.

**Attempts**

The following array has been defined in a hiera.yaml file:

```
hiera_array: 
  - host1
  - host2
  - host3
```

In an attempt to reuse it, the hiera_array is set to be used by another hiera array:

```
reuse::hiera_array:
  - "%{hiera('hiera_array')}"
```

**Expected outcome**

There should be no discrepancy between the files if `hiera_array` or `reuse::hiera_array` is called:

filename.erb

```
<%= scope.function_hiera(['reuse::hiera_array']).join("\n") %>
```

/path/to/filename

```
host1
host2
host3
```

**Current outcome**

However the filename.erb template that calls the array returns:

/path/to/filename

```
-host1
-host2
-host3
+["host1, host2, host3"]
```

Removing the `join` from the templates indicates that the looked up hiera array looks different:

`["[\"host1\", \"host2\", \"host3\"]"]` vs. `["host1", "host2", "host3"]`

**Discussion**

It looks like that the hiera_array can be reused as `["host1, host2, host3"]` is returned and looks like an array. However the hiera or the erb function `<%= scope.function_hiera(['reuse::hiera_array']).join("\n") %>` interprets it as a string.

**Question**

How to reuse Hiera arrays in Puppet?

Comment: I'm a little baffled by the fact that you pass an Array argument to Hiera in `scope.function_hiera(['reuse::hiera_array'])` and still get a result. Why do you construct an Array parameter?

Comment: @FelixFrank the `.join("\n")` requires that it is an array. Could you explain how you would solve the issue? I do think that I do not understand the question.

Comment: The join expects the **result** of the Hiera call to be an array. The **parameter** should (must?) always be a string. I.e. `scope.function_hiera('reuse::hiera_array')`.

Comment: @FelixFrank I have updated the question. Looking up the hiera array results in a different formatted array.

Comment: I'm not talking about *removing the join*. I'm talking about removing the brackets. `scope.function_hiera('reuse::hiera_array').join("\n")`. The `[` and `]` are not useful in this context as far as I can tell. The behavior you are observing also makes me wonder wether you should omit the `"` quotes in your YAML **and** why you perform the lookup in yet another array. Try `reuse::hiera_array: %{hiera('hiera_array')}`.

Comment: @FelixFrank Thank you for the advice. I have tried it and it results in `Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line X column Y`. It seems that double quotes are required to lookup the hiera variable.